# How to ModelBind JSON to a nested object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, json.net

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 and C#. I have this class:

```
public class JobTitle
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public MinimumRequirements MinimumRequirements;


    public JobTitle(DataRow row)
    {
        ID = Utilities.SafeInt(row["JobTitle_ID"]);
        Title = Utilities.SafeString(row["Job_Title"]);

        MinimumRequirements = new MinimumRequirements()
        {
            Certifications = Utilities.SafeInt(row["....."]),
            ID = Utilities.SafeInt(row["....."]),
            Languages = Utilities.SafeString(row["....."]),
            MinimumEducation = Utilities.SafeString(row["....."]),
            MinimumGrade = Utilities.SafeString(row["....."]),
            MinimumYOS = Utilities.SafeInt(row["....."])
        };
    }
}
```

And the JSON being sent looks like this:

```
{
"ID": 401,
"Title": "MinReq",
"MinimumRequirements": {
    "ID": 0,
    "MinimumEducation": "Bachelors",
    "MinimumGrade": "93",
    "MinimumYOS": 10,
    "Certifications": 1,
    "Languages": "English"
}}
```

Here's the signature of my c# controller method:
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult JobTitle(JobTitle jobTitle, bool doUpdate = true)

The ID and Title properties come in and populated with data, all fine. But the MinimumRequirements nested object comes in null.

I also tried this:

[HttpPut]
public ActionResult JobTitle([Bind(Prefix = "MinimumRequirements")]JobTitle jobTitle, bool doUpdate = true)

(that didn't work either)

Here's a screenshot from the VS debugger so you know how the binding looks:

[image: JSON binding to object]

Any idea why the nested object isn't binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `JobTitle` class `MinimumRequirements` must be a [`property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), not a [`field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx).

So replace:

```
public MinimumRequirements MinimumRequirements;
```

with:

```
public MinimumRequirements MinimumRequirements { get; set; }
```

Remember that the default model binder operates only on properties, not on fields.

Also from what I can see your `JobTitle` model doesn't have a parameterless constructor so you cannot use it as action argument because the default model binder won't know how to instantiate it. So make sure that in addition to the constructor that takes a `DataRow` you also have a parameterless constructor or you will have to write a custom model binder for this type if you want it to appear as action parameter.

Comment: Oh STUPID me!! You are right, that fixed it. I actually didn't mean to make that a field, it was just a careless mistake. THANKS!!!

Comment: And just a note on your comment "your JobTitle model doesn't have a parameterless constructor" .... I didn't have to change anything else other than adding the "get;set;" to make it a property. It worked 100% after doing just that.

Comment: Oops, I actually *DO* have a parameterless constructor, and it probably is necessary. I just didn't include it in the post. Sorry. Thanks. I'm done.